# Determining array number from string name

Tags: c++, arrays, string

For example I have such array:

```
name[0] = "Griffin";
name[1] = "David";
name[2] = "John";
name[3] = "Abigail";
```

Then I have in file names ordered in this sequence

```
John
David
Abigail
Griffin
```

How I can determine which array number contains name John, just by reading it's name and without running loops for each entry and checking with statement, because I will have more names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using plain array use `std::map`.

EDIT:

Trivial example

```
   map <string, int> name;
   std::string arr[] = {"Griffin", "David", "John", "Abigail"};
   for(int i=0;i < 3;++i)
   {
       name[arr[i]] = i;
   }
   std::cout <<name["John"]; //prints 2
```

Comment: @Templar : Include `<map>` header.